# How to wrap RHS terms of a formula with a function

Tags: r, formula

I can construct a formula that does what I desire starting with the character versions of terms in a formula, but I'm stumbling in starting with a formula object:

```
form1 <- Y ~ A + B 
form1[-c(1,2)][[1]]
#A + B
```

Now how to build a formula object that looks like:

```
 Y ~ poly(A, 2) + poly(B, 2) + poly(C, 2)
```

Or:

```
 Y ~ pspline(A, 4) + pspline(B, 4) + pspline(C, 4)
```

Seems that it might involve a recursive walk along the RHS but I'm not getting progress. It just occurred to me that I might use

```
> attr( terms(form1), "term.labels")
[1] "A" "B"
```

And then use the `as.formula`(character-expr) approach, but I's sorly of like to see an `lapply (RHS_form, somefunc)` version of a `polyize` (or perhaps `polymer`?) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I borrow some functions I originally wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690068/programmatically-building-formulas-without-string-manipulation/29691154#29691154), you could do something like this. First, the helper functions...

```
extract_rhs_symbols <- function(x) {
    as.list(attr(delete.response(terms(x)), "variables"))[-1]
}
symbols_to_formula <- function(x) {
    as.call(list(quote(`~`), x))    
}
sum_symbols <- function(...) {
    Reduce(function(a,b) bquote(.(a)+.(b)), do.call(`c`, list(...), quote=T))
}
transform_terms <- function(x, f) {
    symbols_to_formula(sum_symbols(sapply(extract_rhs_symbols(x), function(x) do.call("substitute",list(f, list(x=x))))))
}
```

And then you can use

```
update(form1, transform_terms(form1, quote(poly(x, 2))))
# Y ~ poly(A, 2) + poly(B, 2)

update(form1, transform_terms(form1, quote(pspline(x, 4))))
# Y ~ pspline(A, 4) + pspline(B, 4)
```

Comment: I especially like  this because it can also be used to automagically refit a model.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [formula.tools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formula.tools) package that provides various utility functions for working with formulas.

```
f <- y ~ a + b
rhs(f)                        # a + b
x <- get.vars(rhs(f))         # "a" "b"
r <- paste(sprintf("poly(%s, 4)", x), collapse=" + ")  # "poly(a, 4) + poly(b, 4)"
rhs(f) <- parse(text=r)[[1]]
f                             # y ~ poly(a, 4) + poly(b, 4)
```

Comment: +1. Appreciate the pointer to the package. The text manipulation was something I was trying to avoid, though.